# Multiple Words in one Cell, How to separate without delimiting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Due to an erroneous online survey setup, the answers of a multiple choice, select all that apply question have all come together in one cell. For example:

All the selectable options are as follows:

> A12 
>  B1234 
>  C3 
>  D845 
>  E00091 
>  F

Cells with responses look as follows:

Cell A1: `A12C3E00091` 
Cell A2: `B1234F`
Cell A3: `C3D845F`

And there are 100 cells like these with random responses.

I need to somehow automate the data extraction and then count each option.

I tried using Left, Right etc. Its not really helping.

I did use Find and then tried to extract data, but I'm unsure of a function that works from a specific start point within a cell.

If anyone could please help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) would help

Comment: Have you tried using the `instr` function? There are only 6 possibilities you need to check so you could just set up 6 if statements checking each cell and handle each result accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Copy your data to range A2:A101
- into B1:G1, enter A,B,C,D,E,F
- into B2, enter =LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,B$1,""))
- copy B2 to B2:G101

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Copy this into a vba module and use Countwords(RangeString, SearchTerm) as a Cell function:

```
Public Function CountWords(r As String, Search As String) As Integer
Dim a As Variant, str As String, Count As Integer
For Each a In Range(r).Value
    str = str & a
Next a
Count = (Len(str) - Len(Replace(str, Search, ""))) / Len(Search)
CountWords = Count
End Function
```

So =CountWords("A1:A10";"A12") Counts the A12s in the Range A1:A10.

Answer (score 1):

Kartike,

If I understand you right, you want to know which options are represtented in a cell with responses. I would say that you are right to use find. To test if option 1 is in cell A1 run:

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("A12"; A1))
```

which returns TRUE if the string "A12" is included, and FALSE otheriwse. With the answer strings in a column down from A2 and the options strings in a row right from B1 you could get the full table of options by filling the rows and columns with

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND(B$1;$A2))
```

starting from cell B2.

Regards,
Mats

Comment: This basically does the same as my code, but cannot count multiple occurences of the same answer.